# React, Does parent class run lifecycle method when a child class inherit it and mounted?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, inheritance

I know `Child` component can call the `BaseComponent` `setTitle` method.

But, it seems when `Child` component mounted , the `BaseComponent`' lifecycle method `componentDidMount` will not be executed.

```js
class BaseComponent extends React.Component{
    componentDidMount() {
       console.log('baseComponent componentDidMount')
    }
  
    setTitle(title) {
      document.title = title || 'default title'
    }
}
class Child extends BaseComponent{
    constructor() {
        super();
    }
  
    componentDidMount() {
        this.setTitle();
        console.log('child componentDidMount')
    }
  
    render() {
        return <div>react is awesome</div>
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
```

I also know maybe the `HOC` is better solution. And if use `es5`, the `mixins` is the best way.
But that is not my question. So, is it possible to execute `BaseComponent` lifecycle method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should avoid inheritance. Like you said, HOC is the way to go...
For your information, you can call the parent class with super :

```
class Child extends BaseComponent{

    componentDidMount() {
        super.componentDidMount(); // Call the parent class
        this.setTitle();
        console.log('child componentDidMount')
    }

    render() {
        return <div>react is awesome</div>
    }
}
```

Comment: Interesting~ I also make this code `React.Component.prototype.setTitle`. Is it a way do not call `super.someMethod` (because I don't want to call it every time, I want it always execute when every child class `componentDidMount`)and automatic do it in child `componentDidMount` internally?